# Getting Distinct Max Values from Multiple Columns

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, max, greatest-n-per-group

I'm working on a sports database, and I want to write a query that will return the name and the statistical value for certain categories. For example, goal leader, assist leader, points leader, +/- leader, penalty minutes leader, etc. I am using a table called NJDSkaters which contains player names and stats from a specific team. Here is the query code:

```
SELECT CONCAT(PlayerName,' - ',Goals) AS GoalLeader, CONCAT(PlayerName,' - ',Assists)
    CONCAT(PlayerName,' - ',Points) AS PointsLeader
FROM NJDSkaters
WHERE Goals = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Goals) FROM NJDSkaters)
    OR Assists = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Assists) FROM NJDSkaters)
    OR Points = (SELECT DISTINCT MAX(Points) FROM NJDSkaters);
```

Here is a snippet from my skater register table which will show the players who should be returned by this query:

[image: http://imgur.com/T8gi368]

As you can see, my desired return query should have 'Ilya Kovalchuk - 37' returned as GoalLeader, 'Patrik Elias - 52' as AssistLeader, and 'Ilya Kovalchuk - 83' as PointsLeader. Running the query does provide these results, but there is extra information included that I do not want, as you can see here:

[image: http://imgur.com/UUxM2yA]

My question is, how do i get rid of the excess information? I only want the leaders in each category, and I don't want to see the #2 player listed, even if that player is #1 in some other category. Essentially, what I'm saying, is I want only 1 row in this table. Before, I had code that would return all players with the leaders at the top, so this code is a step closer to my desired result, but now I'm stuck. Searching for an answer to this problem has been challenging, as finding a way to ask it generally is difficult.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to PIVOT your data, I would use something like this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(CASE WHEN NJDSkaters.Goals=mx.goals
       THEN CONCAT(PlayerName,' - ', NJDSkaters.Goals) END) GoalLeader,
  MAX(CASE WHEN NJDSkaters.Assists=mx.assists
       THEN CONCAT(PlayerName,' - ', NJDSkaters.Assists) END) AssistsLeader,
  MAX(CASE WHEN NJDSkaters.Points=mx.points
       THEN CONCAT(PlayerName,' - ', NJDSkaters.Points) END) PointsLeader
FROM
  NJDSkaters INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(Goals) goals, MAX(Assists) assists, MAX(Points) points
    FROM NJDSkaters) mx
  ON NJDSkaters.Goals=mx.goals
     OR NJDSkaters.Assists=mx.assists
     OR NJDSkaters.Points=mx.points
```

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f37c1/1).
You might also want to use GROUP_CONCAT instead of MAX in case that more than one player shares the same maximum value:

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN  NJDSkaters.Goals=mx.goals
       THEN PlayerName END), ' - ', mx.goals) GoalLeader,
  CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN NJDSkaters.Assists=mx.assists
       THEN PlayerName END), ' - ', mx.assists) AssistsLeader,
  CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN NJDSkaters.Points=mx.points
       THEN PlayerName END), ' - ', mx.points) PointsLeader
FROM
  NJDSkaters INNER JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(Goals) goals, MAX(Assists) assists, MAX(Points) points
    FROM NJDSkaters) mx
  ON NJDSkaters.Goals=mx.goals
     OR NJDSkaters.Assists=mx.assists
     OR NJDSkaters.Points=mx.points
```

A little explanation:

- The subquery `mx` will return the maximum number of goals, the maximum number of assists, and the maximum points
- I'm joining the table `NJDSkaters` with this subquery to return all of the rows that have the maximum number of goals OR the maximum number of assists OR the maximum points
- `CASE WHEN NJDSkaters.Goals=mx.goals THEN PlayerName END` will return the `PlayerName` if that player has the maximum number of goals, otherwise it will return NULL. The same goes for assists and points.
- using GROUP_CONCAT I'm concatenating all of the players names returned by the CASE WHEN. GROUP_CONCAT will skip NULL values and will only concatenate players that have the maximum value for their category
- using CONCAT I'm concatenating the string returned by the GROUP_CONCAT above with the maximum value for each category.

Comment: Thank you very much. I started this project earlier this semester as just a simple database that we just had to load data and write simple queries, but I wanted to expand and build on it and learn some new techniques. This was really helpful, especially showing two ways at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

why not to limit the result by using LIMIT 1?